# Issue with FastAGI's get_data function always returning 1 instantly

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, asterisk, fastagi

So I've implemented fastagi however I'm having an issue with the get_data function to play an audio file, receive DTMF from the end user and have that returned. The issue I'm having is that everything seems to kick-off ok, but the audio file is not playing (This same file works with agi and fastagi is able to access it) and the function returns 1 instantly. Please see below the log extracts, I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and asterisk 13.1.0:

Log:

```
<SIP/208_fleek-00000008>AGI Rx << VERBOSE "IVRs found = 1" 1
agi://192.168.20.144/agi-bin/ivr.php,fleek,5,1,,23: IVRs found = 1
<SIP/208_fleek-00000008>AGI Tx >> 200 result=1
<SIP/208_fleek-00000008>AGI Rx << GET DATA /usr/share/asterisk/sounds/fleek_ivr 2000 10
 -- <SIP/208_fleek-00000008> Playing '/usr/share/asterisk/sounds/fleek_ivr.slin' (language 'en')
<SIP/208_fleek-00000008>AGI Rx << VERBOSE "Selection detected: 1" 1
 agi://192.168.20.144/agi-bin/ivr.php,fleek,5,1,,23: Selection detected: 1
<SIP/208_fleek-00000008>AGI Tx >> 200 result=1
```

php code:

```
        $name = '/usr/share/asterisk/sounds/fleek_ivr';
            $timeout = $row2['timeout'];
            $ntimeout = 2000;
            $expect = '10';
            $ivr = $fastagi->get_data($name,$ntimeout,$expect);
            $fastagi->verbose("Selection detected: ".$ivr['result']);
            $dtmf = $ivr['result'];
```

Dialplan Code:

```
[function_ivr]
exten => _X.,1,Answer()
 same => n,Noop('type is ${dtype}..... type id is ${dtype_id} BLABLABLABLA)
 same => n,AGI(ivr.php)
 same => n,AGI(agi://X.X.X.X/agi-bin/ivr.php,fleek,5,1,,23
 same => n,Hangup
```

Comment: Use following for debug asterisk -r agi set debug on After that call DEBUG is **OFFTOPIC** on SO

Comment: The log extract has agi debugging enabled

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk requires an ANSWER first in order to get this to work

Comment: This is not true. If channel support early media getdata and read may work before answer(for some providers)

Comment: Hi @arheops thanks for your response. I've tried with early media but haven't been able to get it to work without answering the channel

Comment: You say "asterisk require". That is not true at all. Your provider may not support needed features, thats all. Asterisk not require anything like that.